# OpenCV Android: Define and save ROI in new Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, runtime-error

I am trying to slice (crop) part of my image to another so it can be worked on separately. I have found contours and now trying to save every contour in new Mat but it is giving error

```
Mat crop;
Imgproc.findContours(m, contours, new Mat() ,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL , Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for(int i=0; i <contours.size();i++)
{
    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
    crop = m.submat(rect);
}

Utils.matToBitmap(crop, bm);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Here m is my Mat where image is saved

Error:
[image: Error]

Comment: try giving your crop Mat a size larger than your ROI

Comment: Can you please provide me with code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I always do in this situation is to create a new mat using the constructor with a rect:

```
Mat cropped = new Mat(mOriginal, boudingRect);
```

Edit:

Your bitmap should also have the same size:

```
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(crop.size().width,crop.size().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: @HelpingDesk The problem is with the bitmap. You're trying to save in a bitmap with a different size. You need to create bm with the same size as crop.

Comment: Edited. Notice that when you call `matToBitmap` opencv will require a bitmap with the same size as the mat.

Comment: The method createBitmap is not valid for arguments (double,double,Bitmap.config) ??

Comment: Well Thanks for your help @Pedro Oliveira It worked but I am not getting the results that I want :/ can you please look at my question here for better understanding? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184697/opencv-android-copy-part-of-an-image-to-new-mat

Comment: Remember that you're just using the last cropped image. If you want to get all the cropped rectangles you need to reformulate your `for` code to save every bounding rectangle INSIDE the for.

Comment: Have you seen the other question? I know I'm displaying the last image only but but it is showing the black rectangle.

Comment: Yes I read. Maybe because the black rectangle is a contour itself. I suggest you start checking the area of the `rect` and print it out. This will give you an idea of the content of your image. Then you can filter them by area, by width or height. For testing purposes, displaying only the last image is not a good way to go. Try displaying the 10th or something like that. Or display them all with a wait of 2000ms for example.

Comment: I tried croping and displaying all contours and what i get is that same black rectangle in every contour

Comment: Solved by using MyImage.clone() in findcontours method

Comment: Can we talk on chat? This is my first project on image processing and I am facing lot of difficulties to understand things. Would be very nice of you

Comment: I am ran into another problem can you please look at that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681994/find-total-number-of-pixels-in-contour-opencv-android-java?noredirect=1#comment47501658_29681994